# Change preview URL to local in Storyblok Visual Editor

Tags: headless, headless-cms, storyblok

I am coming back to Storyblok after a few years of not using it and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to switch the visual editor to show my local environment, can anyone guide me?

I looked in the documentation but the only thing I found was the location where to add more preview URLs in settings, not how to actually switch between those URLs within the visual editor.

I'm not sure if it's because I'm currently in a demo space or because the UI changed to the point that I can't decipher it!

So first I added a few test URLs including my localhost, which is the one I want to display on my visual editor:

[image: visual editor settings w/ multiple preview URLs]

But when I go to the visual editor, I recall there being a dropdown at the spot where it says `https://www.my-company.com/home-page`, but there is no drop down and I can't find where to change it to localhost or to testing.com anywhere on the page!!

[image: visual editor]

Answer (score 0):

indeed, you were right with your statement “I'm not sure if it's because I'm currently in a demo space”.

When you are checking a demo, for inspiration or for showcasing to someone else the capabilities of Storyblok, the *Preview URL* is hardcoded to the FE preview environment that the team has developed.

In order to use your own Preview URLs, you will need to create a new space, see how it looks in the Nuxt Tutorial:
[image: Preview URL pointing to localhost in the Visual Editor from Storyblok]
https://www.storyblok.com/tp/add-a-headless-CMS-to-nuxt-3-in-5-minutes#enabling-the-visual-editor

Can you see the `Change URL` button? That's the one that open the list of Preview URLs, what you were looking for.

I hope this helps you!